Issue with dynamic SVG rendering from JavaScript
I am foraying back into the world of web development, so there is a good chance that this is something silly I have overlooked.
I have been able to dynamically create all the HTML components for the SVG I am trying to create, however the resulting image isn't displayed in it's container. My aim is to create an SVG element with a random number of circles, this needs to be repeatable so that I can display more than one on the page at a time.
This is an example of what my code outputs:


<svg class="canvas" id="gen1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
 <filter id="shadow">
   <feDropShadow dx="0" dy="10" stdDeviation="2" flood-opacity="0.4"></feDropShadow> 
 </filter>
 <radialGradient id="highlight" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="25%">
  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FF4D4D"></stop>
  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#8B0000"></stop>
 </radialGradient>
 <circle id="circle1" cx="500" cy="166.66666666666666" r="83.33333333333333" fill="url(#highlight)" filter="url(#shadow)"></circle>
 <circle id="circle2" cx="500" cy="666.6666666666666" r="83.33333333333333" fill="url(#highlight)" filter="url(#shadow)"></circle>
 <circle id="circle3" cx="166.6666666666669" cy="744.0169358562925" r="83.33333333333333" fill="url(#highlight)" filter="url(#shadow)"></circle>
 <circle id="circle4" cx="750.0000000000001" cy="599.6793685588859" r="83.33333333333333" fill="url(#highlight)" filter="url(#shadow)"></circle>
</svg>



If I take the above code and paste it into an online SVG viewer the output is exactly what I expect it to be. However inside the basic page I have built it doesn't show any of the circles, even though when I inspect the HTML I can see all these elements there.
This is the code I am using to generate the SVG:


let canvases = [
    {
        number: 1,
        target: 9,
        circles: [{
            id: 1,
            x: 500,
            y: 166.66666666666666,
            color: "#33FFD4"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            x: 500,
            y: 666.6666666666666,
            color: "#33FFD4"
        }]
    },
    {
        number: 2,
        target: 5,
        circles: [{
            id: 1,
            x: 166.6666666666669,
            y: 744.0169358562925,
            color: "#33FFD4"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            x: 750.0000000000001,
            y: 599.6793685588859,
            color: "#33FFD4"
        }]
    }
];

class Node {
    constructor(type = "div", attributes = [], content = null, childNodes = null) {
        this.type = type;
        this.attributes = attributes;
        this.content = content;
        this.childNodes = childNodes;
    }
}

class Attribute {
    constructor(type = "class", value = null) {
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

function buildCanvas(canvasNumber) {
    let canvas = buildNode(new Node("div", [new Attribute("class", "canvas"), new Attribute("id", "gen" + canvasNumber)], undefined, [
        new Node("h1", [new Attribute("class", "canvasTitle"), new Attribute("id", "canvas" + canvasNumber + "Title")], "Canvas " + canvasNumber),
        new Node("svg", [new Attribute("ns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"), new Attribute("class", "canvas"), new Attribute("id", "canvas" + canvasNumber + "Layout"), new Attribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"), new Attribute("viewBox", "0 0 1000 1000")], undefined,  [
            new Node("filter", [new Attribute("ns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"), new Attribute("id", "shadow")], undefined, [
                new Node("feDropShadow", [new Attribute("ns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"), new Attribute("dx", "0"), new Attribute("dy", "10"), new Attribute("stdDeviation", "2"), new Attribute("flood-opacity", "0.4")])
            ]),
            new Node("radialGradient",  [new Attribute("ns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"), new Attribute("id", "highlight"), new Attribute("cx", "50%"), new Attribute("cy", "50%"), new Attribute("r", "50%"), new Attribute("fx", "50%"), new Attribute("fy", "25%")], undefined, [
                new Node("stop", [new Attribute("ns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"), new Attribute("offset", "0%"), new Attribute("stop-color", "#FF4D4D")]),
                new Node("stop", [new Attribute("ns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"), new Attribute("offset", "100%"), new Attribute("stop-color", "#8B0000")])
            ])
        ].concat(drawHole(canvases[canvasNumber - 1]))),
        new Node("h3", [new Attribute("class", "canvasTarget"), new Attribute("id", "canvas" + canvasNumber + "Target")], "Target " + canvases[canvasNumber - 1].target),
        new Node("div", [new Attribute("class", "canvasScores"), new Attribute("id", "canvas" + canvasNumber + "Scores")])
    ]));
    return canvas;
}

function drawHole(canvas) {
    const circlePositions = canvas.circles;
    let circleNum = 1;
    let circles = [];
    circlePositions.forEach(circle => {
        circles.push(new Node("circle", [
            new Attribute("ns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"),
            new Attribute("id", "circle" + circleNum),
            new Attribute("cx", circle.x),
            new Attribute("cy", circle.y),
            new Attribute("r", 1000/12),
            new Attribute("fill", "url(#highlight)"),
            new Attribute("filter", "url(#shadow)")]))
        circleNum++;
    });

    return circles;
}

function buildNode(node = new Node("div")) {
    let nodeComp = document.createElement(node.type);
    if (node.attributes != null && typeof node.attributes !== "undefined" && node.attributes.length > 0) {
        let ns;
        for (let position = 0; position < node.attributes.length; position++) {
            if (node.attributes[position].type == "ns") {
                ns = node.attributes[position].value;
                nodeComp = document.createElementNS(ns, node.type);
                continue;
            }
            if (ns != null && typeof ns !== "undefined") {
                try {
                    nodeComp.setAttributeNS(ns, node.attributes[position].type, node.attributes[position].value);
                    continue;
                }
                catch (err) {

                }
            }
            let attribute = document.createAttribute(node.attributes[position].type);
            attribute.value = node.attributes[position].value;
            nodeComp.setAttributeNode(attribute);
        }
    }
    if (node.content != null && typeof node.content !== "undefined") {
        nodeComp.innerHTML = node.content;
    }
    if (node.childNodes != null && typeof node.childNodes !== "undefined" && node.childNodes.length > 0) {
        for (let childNode = 0; childNode < node.childNodes.length; childNode++) {
            nodeComp.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", buildNode(node.childNodes[childNode]));
        }
    }
    return nodeComp;
}

document.getElementById("canvas-container").insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", buildCanvas(1));
<div id="canvas-container"></div>



If anyone can spot my mistake or niggle to make the circles display on the canvas please put me out of my misery.

While SVG elements reside in the SVG namespace, their attributes typically do not i.e. you need to use setAttribute to create most SVG attributes.


let canvases = [
    {
        number: 1,
        target: 9,
        circles: [{
            id: 1,
            x: 500,
            y: 166.66666666666666,
            color: "#33FFD4"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            x: 500,
            y: 666.6666666666666,
            color: "#33FFD4"
        }]
    },
    {
        number: 2,
        target: 5,
        circles: [{
            id: 1,
            x: 166.6666666666669,
            y: 744.0169358562925,
            color: "#33FFD4"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            x: 750.0000000000001,
            y: 599.6793685588859,
            color: "#33FFD4"
        }]
    }
];

class Node {
    constructor(type = "div", attributes = [], content = null, childNodes = null) {
        this.type = type;
        this.attributes = attributes;
        this.content = content;
        this.childNodes = childNodes;
    }
}

class Attribute {
    constructor(type = "class", value = null) {
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    }
}

function buildCanvas(canvasNumber) {
    let canvas = buildNode(new Node("div", [new Attribute("class", "canvas"), new Attribute("id", "gen" + canvasNumber)], undefined, [
        new Node("h1", [new Attribute("class", "canvasTitle"), new Attribute("id", "canvas" + canvasNumber + "Title")], "Canvas " + canvasNumber),
        new Node("svg", [new Attribute("ns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"), new Attribute("class", "canvas"), new Attribute("id", "canvas" + canvasNumber + "Layout"), new Attribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"), new Attribute("viewBox", "0 0 1000 1000")], undefined,  [
            new Node("filter", [new Attribute("ns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"), new Attribute("id", "shadow")], undefined, [
                new Node("feDropShadow", [new Attribute("ns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"), new Attribute("dx", "0"), new Attribute("dy", "10"), new Attribute("stdDeviation", "2"), new Attribute("flood-opacity", "0.4")])
            ]),
            new Node("radialGradient",  [new Attribute("ns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"), new Attribute("id", "highlight"), new Attribute("cx", "50%"), new Attribute("cy", "50%"), new Attribute("r", "50%"), new Attribute("fx", "50%"), new Attribute("fy", "25%")], undefined, [
                new Node("stop", [new Attribute("ns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"), new Attribute("offset", "0%"), new Attribute("stop-color", "#FF4D4D")]),
                new Node("stop", [new Attribute("ns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"), new Attribute("offset", "100%"), new Attribute("stop-color", "#8B0000")])
            ])
        ].concat(drawHole(canvases[canvasNumber - 1]))),
        new Node("h3", [new Attribute("class", "canvasTarget"), new Attribute("id", "canvas" + canvasNumber + "Target")], "Target " + canvases[canvasNumber - 1].target),
        new Node("div", [new Attribute("class", "canvasScores"), new Attribute("id", "canvas" + canvasNumber + "Scores")])
    ]));
    return canvas;
}

function drawHole(canvas) {
    const circlePositions = canvas.circles;
    let circleNum = 1;
    let circles = [];
    circlePositions.forEach(circle => {
        circles.push(new Node("circle", [
            new Attribute("ns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"),
            new Attribute("id", "circle" + circleNum),
            new Attribute("cx", circle.x),
            new Attribute("cy", circle.y),
            new Attribute("r", 1000/12),
            new Attribute("fill", "url(#highlight)"),
            new Attribute("filter", "url(#shadow)")]))
        circleNum++;
    });

    return circles;
}

function buildNode(node = new Node("div")) {
    let nodeComp = document.createElement(node.type);
    if (node.attributes != null && typeof node.attributes !== "undefined" && node.attributes.length > 0) {
        let ns;
        for (let position = 0; position < node.attributes.length; position++) {
            if (node.attributes[position].type == "ns") {
                ns = node.attributes[position].value;
                nodeComp = document.createElementNS(ns, node.type);
                continue;
            }
            if (ns != null && typeof ns !== "undefined") {
                try {
                    nodeComp.setAttribute( node.attributes[position].type, node.attributes[position].value);
                    continue;
                }
                catch (err) {

                }
            }
            let attribute = document.createAttribute(node.attributes[position].type);
            attribute.value = node.attributes[position].value;
            nodeComp.setAttributeNode(attribute);
        }
    }
    if (node.content != null && typeof node.content !== "undefined") {
        nodeComp.innerHTML = node.content;
    }
    if (node.childNodes != null && typeof node.childNodes !== "undefined" && node.childNodes.length > 0) {
        for (let childNode = 0; childNode < node.childNodes.length; childNode++) {
            nodeComp.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", buildNode(node.childNodes[childNode]));
        }
    }
    return nodeComp;
}

document.getElementById("canvas-container").insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", buildCanvas(1));
<div id="canvas-container"></div>




You can use the node interface but it's very verbose.  Maybe you ran into trouble creating a svg element dynamically, I think you have to use createElementNS.
A simpler approach is just to write html out.


function buildCanvas() {
  const div = document.querySelector("#svg_goes_here");
  
  div.innerHTML = `<svg class="canvas" id="gen1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
 <filter id="shadow">
   <feDropShadow dx="0" dy="10" stdDeviation="2" flood-opacity="0.4"></feDropShadow> 
 </filter>
 <radialGradient id="highlight" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="25%">
  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#FF4D4D"></stop>
  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#8B0000"></stop>
 </radialGradient></svg>`;
 
 const svg = div.querySelector("svg");
 
 const ballPositions = [
  {x: 100, y: 100},
  {x: 300, y: 200}
 ];
 
 ballPositions.forEach(ball => {
   let circle = `<circle cx='${ball.x}' cy='${ball.y}' r='${1000/12}' fill='url(#highlight)' filter='url(#shadow)'></circle>`;
   svg.innerHTML += circle;
 });
}

buildCanvas();
<div id='svg_goes_here'></div>




My buildNode function does us the createElementNS when I pass an attribute of type "ns" which I do for the SVG and circle creation. I moved from HTML direct as adding the circles after caused them not to load due to the way browsers handle the HTML change vs element appending.

OK, I'm not sure about the problem with the browsers handling html change, does it happen with my example?

Your example is working for me, just hesitant to go back to what I came from for a similar reason. Also most advise seems to be to avoid innerHTML editing when introducing new elements.

There are reasons why .innerHTML should be avoided in many cases but as you clearly want to start with a new SVG here every time, generating the SVG text and assigning it to svg.innerHTML seems simple and effective to me.

and the xmlns attribute is now no longer required, as the browser converts the <svg> String to the proper nameSpace

OP writes:

this needs to be repeatable so that I can display more than one on the page at a time.

You then are going to run into trouble, because the id="shadow" and id="highlight" are global ID values
That means every next SVG you add to the page is going to use the settings (id references) from the first SVG
No issue, until you make that filter and highlight dynamic.. the SVG will still use the values from the first SVG in the page.
You can counter that by creating the SVG inside a shadowRoot so ID values are scoped
With a native JavaScript Custom Element defining a <svg-circles> Web Component
That makes your HTML:
    <svg-circles></svg-circles>
    <svg-circles count="5" color="blue"></svg-circles>
    <svg-circles count="15" color="gold"></svg-circles>



customElements.define("svg-circles", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    const random = (low, high) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low + 1)) + low;
    const dx = random(5,25);
    const dy = random(5,25);
    const count = this.getAttribute("count") || random(3,8);
    const color = {
      blue: ["lightblue","blue"],
      red:  ["lightcoral","red"],
      gold: ["gold","goldenrod"],
    }[this.getAttribute("color")||"red"]
    this.attachShadow({mode:"open"})
      .innerHTML = `<svg part="mainsvg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">` +
      `<filter id="shadow"><feDropShadow dx="${dx}" dy="${dy}" stdDeviation="2" flood-opacity="0.4"/></filter>` +
      `<radialGradient id="highlight" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="25%">` +
      `<stop offset=  "0%" stop-color="${color[0]}"/>` +
      `<stop offset="100%" stop-color="${color[1]}"/>` +
      `</radialGradient>` +
      new Array(~~count).fill().map(_ => {
        const cx = random(100, 900);
        const cy = random(100, 900);
        return `<circle cx='${cx}' cy='${cy}' r='${70}' fill='url(#highlight)' filter='url(#shadow)'/>`
      }).join("") +
      `</svg>`;
  }
})
svg-circles::part(mainsvg) {
  height: 170px;
  background: beige;
}
<svg-circles></svg-circles>
<svg-circles count="5" color="blue"></svg-circles>
<svg-circles count="15" color="gold"></svg-circles>



